# Why does the compiler still warn me about unsafe strtok even after I define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS?

Tags: c++, strtok

I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop.

I always get error

```
Error C4996: 'strtok': This function or variable may be unsafe.
  Consider using strtok_s instead.
  To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.
  See online help for details.
```

When I try to build the following:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char the_string[81], *p;
    cout << "Input a string to parse: ";
    cin.getline(the_string, 81);
    p = strtok(the_string, ",");
    while (p != NULL) {
        cout << p << endl;
        p = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Why am I getting this error even though I define `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`, and how do I fix it?

Comment: There is no question and no sense at all. Why not simply using `strtok_s` ? What's the problem ?

Comment: Your `#define` should in any case be *before* `#include "stdafx.h"` or alternatively put it in your project properties under C++/Preprocessor definitions.

Comment: The solution is to 1) read the details in the online help, and 2) use `strtok_s` instead, as suggested  - or use C++ functions instead of C. Do *not* switch off warnings.

Comment: @Blacktempel Because `strtok_s` is a proprietary library extension and thus not portable.

Answer (score 7):

Your #define doesn't work because of the content of your precompiled header file (stdafx.h).  The boilerplate one looks like this:

```
#pragma once
#include "targetver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
```

It is the last two #includes that cause the problem, those .h files themselves already #include string.h.  Your #define is therefore too late.

Beyond defining the macro in the compiler settings instead, the simple workaround is to just move the #define into your stdafx.h file.  Fix:

```
#pragma once
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "targetver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
```

Answer (score 6):

This may be an old post but I had a similar problem recently.
I went into the project options -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> added _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS to the list of Preprocessor Definitions.
This way you don´t have to put it in every file.

Answer (score 2):

Try following.

```
#pragma warning (disable : 4996)
```

Note the error number is C4996.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you switched on a compiler option that forces the compiler to consider all warnings as errors. Either switch off this option or indeed use macro _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS